# Android not connecting to pc (ADB)

Tags: android, usb, adb, usb-debugging

I have been trying to connect my Huawei phone to pc but there is some problem. I turned on USB debugging and also turned on Allow ADB debugging in charge-only mode but still, this problem persists. I plugged the USB cable into a different USB port but still, I can't connect my phone to pc.

Comment: What is your android version

Comment: It's 8.0 @Jamebes

Answer (score 1):

Try to Enable the following:

- Always prompt when connecting to USB.
- Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode.
- Verify apps over USB.
- Increase readability under sunlight.

Comment: These all options are enabled already but still, I don't understand why my phone connects with my laptop but not with my pc. @Moataz

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to try with the USB mode (***Transferring media files via USB***). USB debugging is a feature which allow developer to debug/run application on physical android device. So, this includes file transfer between pc and your device. If the problem still persists, please check the USB cable.

[This article](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) is an official documentation from google. I hope it will give you more insights about USB debugging.

Comment: today I tried a different pc and it worked great I used the same USB cable. I think the problem only occurs with my desktop HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF I think my pc is old maybe that is the reason. What do you think? and I can't click the article you mention above can you please recheck it? Thanks @senye

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working. I've checked my answer and corrected it. I can't be sure but sometimes antivirus has some effects (may be).